# Generate 256bits Key Rijndael in PHP

Tags: c#, php, rijndael, rijndaelmanaged

The below code will successfully generate KEY for encryption. How can I recreate this in PHP using the same salt and passkey to generate a KEY in order to decrypt the message?

```
public static string GenerateKey(string passkey)
{
    var myAlg = new RijndaelManaged()
    {
         Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
         Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
         KeySize = 256,
         BlockSize = 256,
    };
    byte[] salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some salt value");
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes keys = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passkey, salt);
    myAlg.Key = keys.GetBytes(myAlg.KeySize / 8);
    return (Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myAlg.Key));
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php

Mcrypt supports Rijndael-256